# XMLSEQUENCE() in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I am not able to understand what is the use of XMLSEQUENCE() function in Oracle. I am using a code where

```
Select XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(Some_XML,Some_Xpath)) from dual;
```

Suppose I have Some_XML

```
           <a>
           <b>
           <c>
           <d>4</d>

           </c>
           </b>
           </a>
```

and   Some_Xpath= `'/<b>'`

Now my question is the EXTRACT function is going to return

```
<b> <c> <d>4</d> </c> </b>
```

What is XMLSEQUENCE going to do on this XML and return.

Comment: In short please let me know what does XMLSEQUENCE if passed an XMLtype

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions226.htm

Comment: Suppose I have the result of the query in variable 'X' and and I use X.count(); and X(1).getclobval() what are these both calls going to return ?

Answer (score 0):

First off your xpath `'/<b>'` is malformed.  The angle brackets don't belong.

Second, your xpath will only select anything if the root node is `<b>` which it's not.  An xpath of `'//b'` will select every `<b>` node in your XML, or `'/a/b'` will select every b node that is a child of root node a.

Once you've fixed your xpath, the `XMLSEQUENCE` in your query will convert the XMLType returned by the `EXTRACT` to a single column table of XMLTypes named `COLUMN_VALUE` with one record for every XML fragment returned by the `EXTRACT`.  In the case of your XML there would be only one XML fragment and hence only one record in the table.

If you use the `TABLE` operator on your query in the `FROM` clause of an outer select statement you can see the results:

```
select * from table(
select xmlsequence(extract(xmltype('<a>
<b>
<c>
<d>4</d>

</c>
</b></a>'),'/a/b')) from dual);

COLUMN_VALUE                                                                   
----------------------
<b><c><d>4</d></c></b>
```

If you had multiple nodes returned by your xpath you would see multiple records returned:

```
select * from table(
select xmlsequence(extract(xmltype('<a>
<d>4</d>
<d>5</d>
<d>6</d>
</a>'),'/a/d')) from dual);

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
<d>4</d>
<d>5</d>
<d>6</d>
```